# Where can I find accurate, up-to-date information about visa requirements for visitors to Namibia?

Tags: visas, namibia

I have found much conflicting information, including on Namibia's own High Commission/embassy websites for different countries.

Third-party sites rarely included dated information, so one has no idea when it was last updated, and also contradict each other.

I have not been able to find the information I need on [Namibia's own foreign ministry website](http://www.mirco.gov.na).

I particularly need accurate information about visa requirements for nationals of other African countries.

Can you recommend a canonical or at least thoroughly reliable source of information?

Comment: What's your country of citizenship? Might narrow it down a bit

Comment: @MarkMayo I need general information appertaining to nationals of numerous different countries.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is what the Namibian Tourism Page](http://www.namibiatourism.com.na/page/visas) has to say about the issue - that visas can be acquired from the nearest consulate or embassy.  Unfortunately, like you, I am unable to find a page clearly stating what nationalities require visas and which ones don't.

Timatic posts the following about visa requirements (this is what airport check-in staff will go by when deciding whether to let you board a flight to Namibia):

> Visa required.
>
> Visa Exemptions:
>
> - Nationals of Namibia.
> - Nationals of Angola, Armenia, Australia, Austria, Azerbaijan, Belarus, Belgium, Botswana, Brazil, Canada,   Cuba,
>     Denmark, Finland, France, Germany, Iceland, Ireland   (Rep.), Italy,
>     Japan, Kazakhstan, Kenya, Kyrgyzstan,   Lesotho, Liechtenstein,
>     Luxembourg, Malawi, Malaysia,   Mauritius, Moldova (Rep.), Mozambique,
>     Netherlands, New Zealand, Norway, Portugal, Russian Fed., Seychelles,   Singapore,
>     South Africa, Spain, Swaziland, Sweden,   Switzerland,
>     Tajikistan,Tanzania, Turkmenistan, USA,   Ukraine, Uzbekistan, Zambia
>     and Zimbabwe traveling as   tourists for a maximum stay of 3 months.

The best way to be sure is going to be to contact the local consulate or embassy of Namibia in your own country, or to contact their Ministry of International Relations and Cooperation in Windhoek to ask them directly.  (If you do this, please advise your findings.)

Comment: Never trust Wikivoyage. The only truly reliable resource is Timatic.

Comment: @JonathanReez Hence my advice to contact Namibian officials directly.

Comment: If that's the answer then we should contact the Namibian officials and post their response :) You can access Timatic here to update your answer: http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/countryinfo.html. It's a much better source than Wikis.

Comment: @JonathanReez Updated :)